# How to modify the output of a view in Drupal 7.x using a module

Tags: mysql, drupal, module, drupal-7, drupal-views

I want to modify the query that is running to create a table in a view but am having a hard time, so to keep it simple I am using a plain view that just lists users in a table and am trying to modify the query to make the table have two columns. I have been looking at the documentation for Drupal queries, trying to find tutorials, and looking at blog posts on how others modified queries in Drupal and Views, but so far none have worked or shown how to do something as simple as this, or I've tried to create simple query statements following what they did with no outcome.

I've mainly been trying to use `hook_views_pre_execute()` but have also tried . This is what my code looks like at the moment:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter().
 */
// This function is called right before the execute process.
function my_module_views_pre_execute(&$view) {
    if ($view->name == 'page' && $view->current_display == 'page') { //checks name of the view and what type it is
        drupal_set_message("I can make changes to the view here.."); //diagnostic information, shows we can make changes to that view
        $query =db_select('node','n')//select base table, alias is n.
            ->fields('n',array('nid', 'title', 'created', 'uid')); //adding fields nid, title, created, uid.
        dpm($query->execute()->fetchAll()); // diagnostic information, shows whats being returned by the query 
        $query->execute()->fetchAll();

        $view->build_info['query'] = $query;
    }
}
```

I am able to create a message on the view with `drupal_set_message("I can make changes to the view here..");`, and in the Views settings tab I enabled 'Show the SQL query' and the output of that is the query from my module/code (it doesn't match the table created by Views).

So why doesn't it affect the table output at all? How do I modify what query is being run to display the view (which is apparently different from the 'Show the SQL query' output)?

Answer (score 1):

I have taken example only for nid here I can provide you just an Idea for alter the views output.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param type $view
 * @param type $query
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter(). This function is Used when we need to Alter the query before executing the query.
 */
function mymodule_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
    if ($view->name == 'VIEW_NAME' && $view->current_display == 'PAGE_NAME') {
    drupal_set_message("I can make changes to the view here.."); //diagnostic information, shows we can make changes to that view
        $query =db_select('node','n')//select base table, alias is n.
            ->fields('n',array('nid', 'title', 'created', 'uid')); //adding fields nid, title, created, uid.
        dpm($query->execute()->fetchAll()); // diagnostic information, shows whats being returned by the query 
        $result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
    $nids = array();
    foreach ($result as $value) {
      $nids[] = $value->nid;
     }
    $view->query->where[1]['conditions'][] = array('field' => "node.nid", "value" => $nids, "operator" => "IN");
  }
}
```

hook_views_pre_execute() is too late in the query build processs so I think you should use hook_views_query_alter().

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I've changed my function to views_query_alter but the new problem is: the views is successfully read the function and return drupal set messages but the function does not apply any changes to query and table. Compare to views_pre_execute function, it alters the query successfully but does not apply some changes to table. For example, i can use views_pre_execute function to change the content in first column. However, i can't add new column from the function even though i add field in my code.